# Click and keypress combined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, keyboard

Hey guys I'm trying to make combine click and keypress on my function, but nothing I've tried so far seems to work.
This is my code:

```
function victoryMessage() {

    $(document).off("keyup", handleKeyUp);
    $('#feedback').append("Bravo!<br><br><div id='replay' class='button'>Nastavi</div>");


    $('#replay').on("click",function () {
        if(questionBank.length>3) {
            gameScreen();
        }
        else {
            finalPage();
        }
    });

    $(document).off("tap", keepFocus).trigger("tap");
}
```

so far I have tried following:

```
$("#replay").on("click keyup", function (e) {
    if (e.type == "click" || e.keyCode == 13) {
        if(questionBank.length>0) {
            gameScreen();
        }
        else {
            finalPage();
        }
    }
});
```

and

```
var callback = function() {
    if(questionBank.length>0) {
        gameScreen();
    }
    else {
        finalPage();
    }   
};

$("#replay").keypress(function() {
    if (event.which == 13) callback();
});

$('#replay').click(callback);
```

and

```
$(document).on("keypress", function(e){
    if (e.which == 13) {
        testKey();
    }
});
```

I have also tried some other things, but nothing seems to work. Here the link so you see my full code in action http://www.wpacademy.nextweb.space/TestingMobile/

 EDIT: To clarify as Andy said I want the click to register when clicking only the the replay button, and the enter key to register when pressed anywhere within the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my tests you cannot keypress a button directly so a possible solution is the following

When the user presses enter anywhere on screen, replace alert with your function call.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    }
});

$("#replay").on("click", function(){
  function call
});
```

Also to avoid having your code run in the keypress event all the time, you can check if a specific element is present on the screen like the replay button.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you this is what I wanted. Also for second part of your answer should I use something like this to acheive it > if ($('#MyId').length) {
    // My Code
}

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 Yes something like the code you provided, or by checking if an element has a class or is visible to the page will do as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you're after. You want the click to register when clicking only the the replay button, and the enter key to register when pressed anywhere within the document.

```js
$(document).on("click keypress", function (e) {      
  if (e.type === "click" && e.target && e.target.id === "replay") {
    e.preventDefault();  
    $("#output span").html("click happened");
  } else if (e.type === "keypress" && e.keyCode === 13) {   
    e.preventDefault();  
    $("#output span").html("enter key anywhere within document happened");
  }
});
```

```css
#output {
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0;
  border: 2px dashed gray;
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="replay">replay button</button>
<div id="output">Event type: <span></span></div>
```

Comment: Your code also works very well and I thank you but as someone who started learning JS relatively recenlty, Petros code was easier for me to understand so I picked his solution. I did upvote you of course :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the element is created via JS, assign the click handler to `document` and defer it to `#replay`. And I'm not sure how you plan on capturing `keyup` on a `div`, but if you set `contenteditable` on the `div`, you can double click on the text, then type in it to show both events are being captured. Here's a codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RpGEWK

```js
$('#feedback').append("Bravo!<br><br><div id='replay' class='button' contenteditable>Nastavi</div>");
$(document).on("click keyup", "#replay", function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="feedback"></div>
```

Comment: you are saying here that all clicks to the document will go to the #replay button but i am not sure that would make sense in this case.

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou I appreciate your comment. I would recommend reading the bottom of https://api.jquery.com/on/ *"Note that .on() allows a click event on any paragraph--even new ones--since the event is handled by the ever-present body element after it bubbles to there."* - they use `$('body').on('click','p',function() {});` but `document` instead of `body` is just as common.

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou *"all clicks to the document will go to the #replay button"* is false. Only clicks on `#replay` in the document go through this event handler. You should read up on the API - this is standard jQuery for new/rendered elements.

Comment: Yes totally right ignore my comment, not sure why i was confused there even though i use deffered calls in my own projects as well.

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou it confused me the first times I saw it :) did you downvote my answer?

Comment: yeah sorry i downvoted but now i cannot upvote you need to update a bit your answer. Sorry about that. Clearly the user wants to check code 13 can you update your answer on that?

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou hah no worries, edited my answer. Glad it was you. I hate it when people downvote and don't give a comment as to why!

Comment: I totally agree with that and i won't do that to someone else without explanation :)

Comment: Btw with your solution i could not test "enter" button keypress. Do you have a solution to that?

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou I'm not sure how OP planned on capturing a `keyup` event on a `div`, but I assumed they had a reason for that. I edited my response with a working example of one way that it could work, just to show that you can capture the `click` and `keyup` in one event handler since that seems to be the purpose of the post.

Comment: Seems there is no way to capture an enter event on a div thats why i used the document instead. Also #replay is a button even though the OP used a div for that. The other answer by Andy Hoffman also uses document to capture the keypress event. Making a button editable to be able to simulate a keypress event is not what the OP wants. Think about it, its a reply button, its a game, when you click the replay button you expect to replay the game not convert the replay button to an editable text placeholder ;p

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou those are fair assumptions, but I'll let OP clarify since you and I are both making assumptions and neither of us is OP. I don't know what they're doing. My answer was just to show how you can combine keyup and click into a single event handler.

Comment: Yp fair enough :)

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou Hey guys thank you both for your help I guess I didn't phrase my question good enough, but Petros understood exactly what I wanted to achieve.